# Copying DIV with working functionality

Tags: jquery, html, copy

I'm working on a script but it doesn't seems to work.
The idea is to copy a DIV and it's jQuery functions, it just stop functioning.

http://tinyurl.com/cr5uft9

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the function and script is all about ? and what the o/p of the code should be ?

Comment: More importantly...how does one actually see this error?  At first glance it appears to be working for me.

Comment: The code is about showing different text upon selections, the dropdown menu is just an explanation menu about the selections.. but should take the buttons with it upon clicking. The clicking should be working upon the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it as `jQuery('#Certificaat').clone(true).appendTo('#CertificaatNieuw');`

Optional parameter in clone() set to true allows to copy with data and events.

Comment: I think this would result in two elements with the same `id` on the page, which is bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the blank .clone() function.
You should rather use [.clone([withDataAndEvents])](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents)

```
jQuery('#Certificaat').clone(true)... // the "true" argument does the job for you.
```